# PHP Custom Order

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a blog and I need help with ordering/sorting. I have a field called order. The following shows how the database is structured:

```
id | name       | order
-------------------------
1  | post one   | 5
2  | post two   | 4
3  | post three | 3
4  | post four  | 2
5  | post five  | 1
```

I can use SQL ORDER BY clause to order based on the field 'order'. What I really want to do is when I change the order of post two to 4, is there a mechanism to order the rest of the rows automatically.

Comment: Which operation exactly?  Updating the order?  Sorting?

Comment: Updating the order from all the records.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume just `ORDER BY` on the `order` field in the database?

---

Now that I understand your question better, how about this: Number your `order` field in tens (`10`, `20`, `30` and so on). Then, when you want to change the order, adjust the numbers (for instance, change `10` to `25` to put it between `20` and `30`). When you're done reordering, run this:

```
SET @order = 0;
UPDATE `posts` SET `order` = (@order := @order+10) ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Comment: I think that the OP want more flexibility, something like an additional column called `display_order`

Comment: "I have a field called order in the database" - I assumed that this meant they just needed the results to sort by that field.

Comment: @Kolink: I think the problem lies if he ever wanted to change the order, how would he go about changing the entire database

Comment: I agree with you - it's not clear. I was thinking that he's having a "fixed" order (which doesn't change) which is kind of "base-line" and a "flexible" order which can be changed

Comment: My question is more about updating the field. I mean like If I change the order of post #1, the rest of the items should be updated right.

Comment: Well, personally I'd either do the ordering in PHP (where I can just use an array to define the order of posts), or BASIC-style numbering (10, 20, 30...) so I can move them around (10 -> 25) and then renumber.